# $\int_a^b\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)dy$ versus $\int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dy$, which is correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question, notation

For a two-variable function $f$, which symbol below is technically correct?

> $$ \int_a^b\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)dy ~~~~~~~ \text{versus} ~~~~~~~ \int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dy$$

The first or the second? Or both? How about $\int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)dy$?

Notice that the point here is that for a two-variable function, can't we use $d/dx$? Must we use $\partial/\partial x$? You may say, there's a rule that whenever dealing with multivariable function, use $\partial$. However, notice that you would write $\frac{df(x,3)}{dx}$ instead of $\frac{\partial f(x,3)}{\partial x}$. Here $f$ itself is a two-variable function, but we're not concerning $f$ itself, but the *expression* $f(x,3)$ (just as you must have seen something like $\frac{d(\sin x+x^2)}{dx}$, imagine that it is the case that the nominatior $(\sin x+x^2)$ is replaced by the expression $f(x,3)$). So the rule that "*whenever dealing with multivariable function, use $\partial$*" does not make sense.

And on the other hand, when **INSIDE** the integral sign, the variable $y$ is somewhat already served as a *constant* (we say the variable is being **binded**), waiting to be integrate after the integrand is completely evaluated (just as in $\sum_{i=1}^{10}i^2$, the variable $i$ inside summation is binded).  So, the all story happen inside the integral sign, is only of one variable $x$. In this way, should we write $\int_a^b\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)dy$?

PS: Feel free to comment or to answer. Any advice or experience is welcomed. :)

Comment: Notation *per se* is meaningless unless the **definition** is given.

Comment: Ya, I adopt the definition as what people literatures usually uses. Notice that there're few paper of analysis that **defined** what $\frac{\partial}{\partial}\cdots$ mean in the paper in the beginning. It is my confusion of such custom definition that I post this.

Comment: There is indeed a precise definition for partial derivatives. But there is no universal *notations* for this concept. I don't understand what you mean by "can't we use $d/dx$". One can use whatever notation as long as it is properly defined, although one could ask if some notation is more convenient or illuminating. But mathematical notations are for communications and there are existent conventions to adopt.

Comment: You can see common notations of partial derivatives used in literatures in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative

Comment: It may be interesting to discuss why "$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)$" is a bad notation though.

Comment: @Jack Why it's bad? :)

Comment: (1)"But mathematical notations are for communications and there are existent conventions to adopt." I would not use it simply because people seldom use it in literatures and there is no need to invent a new one to confuse people. "One **can** use something" does not necessarily mean one **should** use it. (2)"One **can** use whatever notation as long as it is properly defined". Why do you think it *good* in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

For $f : \Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} : (x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ it does not really matter if we write $\displaystyle \frac{df}{dx}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ for the derivative with respect to $x$. It is a matter of emphasis. We usually write $\displaystyle \frac{df}{dx}$ to emphasize we are deriving a function of *one* variable, namely $x$, and $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ to emphasize we are deriving a function of *more than one* variable with respect to the variable named $x$. It is a question of making easier to the reader to know what is going on. It is much more common to use $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in this case.

Now regarding to the technicality, $\displaystyle \int_a^b\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)\ dy$ and $\displaystyle \int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)\ dy$ and $\displaystyle \int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\ dy$ are not correct or incorrect but *inaccurate*.

Derivatives acts on functions, not on points. That is $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ acts on the function $f$ and not on the point $f(x,y)$. Furthermore we derive the function $f$ at the point $(p,q)$ with respect to $x$, we not derive the function $f$ at the point $(x,y)$ with respect to $x$. That is

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} : \Omega \to \mathbb{R} : (p,q) \mapsto \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p,q) $$

The latter one, $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$, creates unnecessary ambiguity. To see that, set $x = 1$; then $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial 1}(1,y)$ or $\displaystyle = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,y)$ or $\displaystyle = \frac{\partial f}{\partial 1}(x,y)$?

Therefere, agreeing we want to avoid ambiguity we would write

$$ \int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p,q)\ dq $$

However it also reasonable to write

$$ \int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p,y)\ dy $$

because the derivative are not binding the variable $y$ in any way.

Let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: By the way, since many (if not 99.999%) people ever use something like $\frac{d}{dx}x^3$, $\frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x$, etc., I'm afraid that the understanding that $\frac{d}{dx}$ or $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ are operators that act on functions (e.g. $f$) is not what most people think.

Comment: By the way, someone has -1 your answer. Then I +1 for your obseveration and opinion. ;)

Comment: Indeed, @Eric. We are talking about a deep understanding of derivation. Anyway have in mind that the use of *shorthands* like $\frac{d}{dx}x^3$ are understood unambiguously and leads to no confusions after a firm grasp of derivation is achieved and we are willing to trade off technicality and accuracy for thinking efficiency and computation speed.

Comment: I really like this answer, it seems to be the clearest explanation of the issue bothering OP. I advise @Eric to accept it, if he agrees!

Answer (score 2):

The integrand is a function of two variables, $x$ and $y$, so use the partial derivative notation *inside* the integral sign.

$$\int\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\,dy$$
or
$$\int\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,y)\,dy$$
are both fine.

The entire integral is a function of one variable, $x$, so use the total derivative notation outside the integral sign.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x,y)\,dy$$

Comment: But the $y$ in $\int_a^b\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}dy$ is a constant, isn't it? Since $y$ is a constant, shouldn't it be $\int_a^b\frac{d f(x,y)}{dx}dy$? Just as you would write something like $\frac{df(x,3)}{dx}$, but not the $\partial$-sign version.

Comment: @Eric No, the $y$ is not constant. It varies from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: When in the integrand, the variable $y$ is binded, just as in $\sum_{i=1}^{100} i^2$, here $i$ is binded. If you wish to differentiate $i$ inside the summation, it is not valid. Similary, when we focus our vision inside the integral sign, $y$ is binded, hence it can and should be treated as a constant. Isn't it?

Comment: @Eric I suppose this has nothing to do with partial derivatives or bound variables. Let's address a more basic question. In the expression $f(x)$, does $x$ represent a single number? And if so, how does any derivative make sense, since we must allow the variable to change? Asking the question is answering it: we _must_ allow ourselves to imagine that variables may vary. In each term of the sum $\sum i^2$, $i$ takes a fixed value, but we must allow ourselves to imagine that $f(i)=i^2$ is a function which can be evaluated at other inputs too. (...)

Comment: Then $\sum \Delta i^2/\Delta i$ also makes sense (using a finite difference operator instead of derivative). And in the integral $\int f(y), dy,$ even though $y$ is a bound variable and for each $y$ value $f(y)$ takes a particular value, we must remember that we are allowed to wonder what would happened if $y$ were allowed to vary, and how $f$ would take different values when it did. So if we believe that, then we believe that $\int df/dy(y)\,dy$ makes sense. We know that the integrand may vary with respect to the variable of integration. (...)

Comment: Once we believe that, it is clear that when differentiating an integrand of two variables, we are doing a partial differentiation. So we write $\int \partial f/\partial x(x,y)\,dy$ instead of $\int df/dx(x,y)\,dy.$ Since it makes sense that $y$ can vary, the derivative with respect to $x$ represents only a _partial_ variation of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most usual notation (and probably most correct) is :

$$\int_a^b\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)dy$$

To justify my saying :

$(1)$ : $f(x,y)$ is a $2$-variable function over $\mathbb R^2$ and hence the derivative with respect to one of its variables (let's say $x$) is notated as :

$$f_x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

$(2)$ : To note what variables/constants etc. the partial derivative is calculated over, one writes them in a parentheses following the notation mentioned above, so the partial derivative of the function $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ involving the variables $(x,y)$ (without it being specified over certain $x_0,y_0$) is :

$$f_x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$$

**Since you've been discussing when you know the number of variables of the function $f$, I'll try to clarify it :**

If on your text, exercise or solution, you have used the following notation :

$$f(x,y) \space \text{such that} \space f : D \to \mathbb R^2 \space\text{where} \space D \subset \mathbb R^2 $$

then that means that $f$ is **strictly** a $2$-variable function, since for example, writing $f$ in that way :

$$f(x,y,0)$$

is **wrong**. Why ? Because the domain that $f$ is set is the set $D$ which is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. This means that the element $(0,0,0)$ cannot be included in $D$ because it's set in $2$ dimensions.

If you are **not** given such a complete notation (which is impossible in books and exercises, since functions are almost always defined first of all as $f : A \to B$ and then as $f(x,\dots)$) then you may argue about the notation. Still, the most convenient and usual way of writing is the one mentioned above. If though, you're given such a notation as mentioned, then there is no question about the variables-dimensions of $f$.

Comment: How if we interprete "$f(x,y)$" as just an *expression*-- imagine something like $x^2+\sin y$, an expression consist of $x, y$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ is something like $\frac{\partial (x^2+\sin y)}{\partial x}$. And hence when you see $x^2+\sin y$, we just don't know how many variable it has. And hence we're not ruled by the rule that "$f$ has two-variable, so we should write $\partial$"

Comment: @Eric The notation $f(x,y)$ resembles to a $2$-variable function over $\mathbb R^2$ if we are talking about the cartesian system of coordinates. In the way you're trying to find holes, elementary one-variable functions such as $f(x)$ that people are taught are schools should go hand-by-hand for higher dimension analysis. The fact is that when you write $f(x)$ you note that $f$ is an one variable function whether when you write $f(x,y,z)$ then $f$ is a $3$ variable function and so on. When you're given $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is wrong to asume that $f(x)=f(x,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: Rebellos: Ya, I know what you mean. But there may be another issue. See my comment in Olivier Oloa's answer.

Comment: @Eric I'll add a final touch to my answer which answers that part.

Comment: Thanks. I've just seen your edit. I agree. I think there's another issue. For example, we would write $\frac{d (\sin x+x^3-2)}{dx}$, $\frac{d (2^x-7)}{dx}$, and $\frac{d f(x,3)}{dx}$, etc. Notice in the last example, $f(x,3)$ is nothing more or less than an expression like $\sin x+x^3-2$. Thus for the same sake and same logic, in the general case, the whole term $f(x,y)$ can be treated as an expression which we don't know how many letters are varying (but the function $f$ itself is always a two-variable function). Thus it seems that we can legally write $\frac{df(x,y)}{dx}$?

Answer (score 0):

The function is *multivariate* anyway, thus the symbol 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)
$$ is clearer than the other one.

Comment: Within the integral sign, $y$ is 
constant, isn't it?

Comment: @Eric Yes, but the symbol gives the same result is with *no ambiguity*...

Comment: Hmm, follow your same logic, will you write something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(3x^2+3)$? These are the same situation.

Comment: I see what you mean, but if you write $f(x,y)=3x^2+3$ then...

Comment: @Eric **IF** you're using the notation : $f(x,y) = 3x^2 + 3$ in your text/writing, then **yes**, the most formal way to denote the derivative is : $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(3x^2+3)$ !

Comment: Exactly what Olivier mentioned up above, we posted it at the same time.

Comment: Yah. It's nice to discuss with you. I think there's a problem that is always blurred in our daily usage of symbols. First, we all agree that we can write something like $\frac{d}{dx}f(x,3)$ right? (Here, notice that $f$ must be a two-variable function, undoubtfully. And notice that the nominator just an "expression".) However, on the other hand, as soon as we see something like "$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$", we think of it that the whole story is of two-variable, so we should use $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$. This is weird.

Comment: Hmm.. my last comment is not clear. I try to rephrase again. Whenvever we see the term "$f(x,y)$" in the symbol $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$,  we actually, really have no idea how many variables we are dealing with . What we only know is that $f$ *itself* is a two variable function. But "$f$ *itself is a two variable function*" is absolutely not what we concern when we're going to applying a (partial or not) differentiation, as my example $\frac{df(x,3)}{dx}$.